# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') on a component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

After setup a simple comment component inside the post component! i'd be cool to redirect to replies component after click on reply!

But, the navigation still pops up these erros:

> TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Or

> undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   '_this2.props.navigation.navigate') onPress

which seems a very common problem!
none of the answers that i saw really simplify and explain why this happen!
So please can anyone clarify why this aways happen?

The piece of code that this is happening is this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

import styles from "../assets/styles";
import Comments from "./Comments";

import ReplyScreen from "./ReplyScreen";
class Comment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      visible: false
    };


  }



  submitReply = (comment, parentId) => {
    this.props.onSubmitReply(comment, parentId);
  };

  render() {
    const comment = this.props.comment;
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.body}>{comment.comment} </Text>
        <Text
          style={{ color: "blue" }}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ReplyScreen")}

          //  onPress={() => {
          /* 1. Navigate to the Details route with params */
          //  navigate("Reply", {
          //  comment: comment.id
          //key: comment.id
          //});
          //  }}
        >
          Reply
        </Text>



        <Comments comments={comment.replies} onSubmitReply={this.submitReply} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

Comment: My guess is that `this.props.navigation` is undefined, ie the property doesn't exist. You're trying to use it like an object (by accessing the `navigate` property), which explain the error message.

Comment: @Halcyon thank you for your comment, but still confused about!

Comment: Can you show us the navigator leading to this view ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can explain it with some code:

```
var my_object = {
    "foo": "lorem ipsum"
};
console.log(my_object.foo); // "lorem ipsum"
console.log(my_object.bar); // undefined
console.log(my_object.bar.foo); // Error!

var my_uninitialized_object;
console.log(my_uninitialized_object); // undefined
console.log(my_uninitialized_object.foo); // Error!
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, thank you Halcyon, but why on their guides -- react-navigation they say to use
 this.props.navigation.navigate?

Comment: I don't know enough about React to know how `this.props.navigate` gets a value. Maybe you've missed something essential when using the code example?